# Will changing the scale of objects in Unity have adverse effects?

Tags: unity

Relative to what they are by default, I mean. For example compared to the character controllers that come with Unity. If I make the character 4 times the size, will that cause problems, with the physics and everything? Or are there just changes in a couple values that I'd need to make?

Does Unity expect that 1 unit will always be around 1 meter?

Comment: Unity does not expect that unit conversion, you can define one that suit your needs. As far as I know, physics in Unity works in a metric system, so if you need to scale objects, make the proper conversions for the physics engine.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point errors will start creeping in if things are *WAY* bigger than Unity expects, but just 4 times bigger should be fine (assuming of course you're consistent with everything!) I'm talking more like if you tried to simulate the entire solar system at 1 unit = 1 meter.

Answer (score 0):

No, scaling an object will not have adverse effects as described by yourself. Physics will still function. And like [@gjocking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/6588/jhocking) mentions in his answer, floating point errors might creep in on a way bigger size.

The only adverse effect scaling has is the **extra draw call** if you are using dynamic batching

- scale changing will break dynamic batching - so you will get one more draw call

  However with static batching you would still get 1 draw call.

> also in case of scaled meshes GPU re-normalization state must be set 
>   (otherwise your lighting will go wonky), therefore scaled and
>   non-scaled meshes can not be batched together.

Also if a non uniform scale is used the mesh will be copied. **ONLY** if non-uniform scale is used. In case of uniform scale (both X, Y and Z scale are equal) Unity will **NOT** make a copy of a mesh and will be completely handled by the GPU.